# Measuring DNS queries, socket connection, etc

Tags: linux, time, socket

As a clumsy approximation, I can measure the process of resolving a DNS name with:

```
 time getent hosts server.com
```

and beautifully see how a uncached query can take about 50ms and cached queries about 5ms in average (a pretty cool difference).

But, how can I do the same to measure a simple socket connection? I'm looking for a command like:

```
time cmd_to_resolve_dns_and_connect_but_no_wait_for_input_or_output
```

or just

```
time cmd_to_download --option-to-ignore-everything-after-socket-connect
```

or just:

```
cmd_to_download --the-suitable-process-halt-command --option-to-print-time
```

Any possibility to know the time of connecting to a (HTTP) server is fine for me (I can of course substract to the time the inner DNS name resolution that the command performs; I know that the option parsing and printing consumes time, etc; I don't need an exact measurement, but the command I need it's not for a script, it's for my eyes).

Comment: I mean, you could pretty trivially write a program to do that. Or I guess you could just use time `nmap`. There might be a set of `nc` args that allow you to connect and then immediately terminate the connection, but nothing lookin' obvious to me from that manpage.

Comment: Maybe `time tcping -n 1 remoteip remoteport`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
time nc -zw60 google.com 80
```

(`nc` comes from the `netcat` package)

Or better readable (output):

```
TIMEFORMAT='%E'
time nc -zw60 google.com 80
```

Comment: Maybe that is what I'm looking for but I'm not sure though, because it says that `-z` "scan for listening daemons"; that doesn't mean that the connection is actually performed, but I don't know either if the time of connecting to a socket after it has been identified is negligible or isn't.

Comment: That command should do something else. I have finally ended by writting a little "C++ script" which resolves and connects to an endpoint with `boost::asio`, and the DNS resolution takes about 4ms (cached), and the `connect` command about 15ms (~20ms). However, your command gives me 80ms, which is four times longer.